# SASS --watch command not fully working

Tags: css, terminal, sass

I have a pretty basic SASS setup running, which includes the following folder structure:

- css
- style.css
- -modules

  - _all.scss
  - _globals.scss
- partials

  - _base.scss
  - _normalize.scss
  - _styles.scss
- vendor

  - -empty

I am telling SASS to watch the following sass --watch modules/_all.scss:style.css --style compact.

The issue is, that one one machine a change to ANY file included in _all.scss is recorded and output properly. On another machine, completely up to date, a change to a partial file thats included in _all.scss does not record a change, and therefore no styles are output. I have to reset SASS to watch the partial _all.scss once more for the change to be recorded.

Has anyone experienced these inconsistencies before? I'm not looking to watch an entire directory as I wish to have only a single stylesheet output...

Both builds have the same version of sass, ruby and command line tools running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the sass-cache is not being busted when you make the change. You can try disabling the cache on the broken machine to see if the problem resolves. If it does, check manually delete the cache directory and try again.

Side note, you shouldn't have to use the watch command with rails (unless you're doing something unique). Sprockets is supposed to have plugins which do this automatically when serving assets.

In fact, I suspect that this may even be a conflict between sprocket's SASS engine configuration and the sass watcher binary configuration.

See the default cache configuration for the sass binary here: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#cache_location-option

Comment: Didn't work, I've updated ruby and sass and all it's dependencies and the --watch command is still ignoring changes... I've even deleted the sass cache folders. Out of ideas here...